# jquery sortable: get id of all items of all sortables list

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a page with a lot of jquery sortable list.
I have the script that controls if the id of a new element alredy exist on the target list.

I need to check if the id of the new element alredy exist on all the list on my page, not only in the target list.

```
 $('#sortable20141230').sortable({
    connectWith: 'ul',
    update: function(event, ui) {
        var prodotti = $(this).sortable('toArray');
        var testata = "20141230";
        var volantino =  "51";

        $.post("ArticoliAssegnazioneDB.php", {testata:testata,  prodotti:prodotti, volantino:volantino}, function(data){
            $("div#tes20141230").html(data);
            //location.reload();
        });
    }
 });

 $('#sortable20141231').sortable({
    connectWith: 'ul',
    update: function(event, ui) {
        var prodotti = $(this).sortable('toArray');
        var testata = "20141231";
        var volantino =  "51";

        $.post("ArticoliAssegnazioneDB.php", {testata:testata,  prodotti:prodotti, volantino:volantino}, function(data){
            $("div#tes20141231").html(data);
            //location.reload();
        });
    }
});

 $('#sortable20141232').sortable({
    connectWith: 'ul',
    update: function(event, ui) {
        var prodotti = $(this).sortable('toArray');
        var testata = "20141232";
        var volantino =  "51";

        $.post("ArticoliAssegnazioneDB.php", {testata:testata,  prodotti:prodotti, volantino:volantino}, function(data){
            $("div#tes20141232").html(data);
            //location.reload();
        });
    }
});
```

In the above example, each script send trought POST to `ArticoliAssegnazioneDB.php` an array with the list of ID of a specific list.
I need to send the list of all ID of all list.

Can someone help me to improve my code?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will do the tricks:

```
var firstList = $('#sortable20141230').sortable('toArray');
var secondList = $('#sortable20141231').sortable('toArray');
var thirdList = $('#sortable20141232').sortable('toArray');
```

Then inside each sortable update you can do:

```
$.post("ArticoliAssegnazioneDB.php", {testata:testata,  listOne: firstList, listTwo: secondList, listThree: thirdList}, function(data){
       $("div#tes20141232").html(data);
       //location.reload();
});
```

Comment: Thank you Deepak, with your suggestion, I found a way to solve my problem.